# How do I use a Town Portal?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

I've built a Basic Town Portal in a town, which states that it allows your hero to teleport from that town to any other town you control.  I've got my hero in the town, but how do I make them teleport?  If I tell them to move to another town, they just start walking there.

Comment: What happens if you put your hero into the town and then click on the portal? (I have actually never played 6, so I am assuming the town interface is similar to the one in 5 or 3)

Comment: If there is no portal to click on, is there an icon on the interface that represents the portal?

Comment: I didn't think it was out for another week? O.o

Comment: Demo version maybe?

Comment: Yes, this is from playing the demo.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Once you've built a Basic Town Portal, all of your heroes gain a **Town Portal Basic** spell in their spellbook.

[image: Spellbook with Town Portal]

When a hero is standing in a town with a Basic Town Portal, they can cast **Town Portal Basic** to teleport to any other towns you own.

According to the mouseover, the spell requires 15 movement points in addition to the 10 mana.

Comment: No it isn't.  However, Town Portal was historically a spell in previous versions of HoMM.